# 'Circle' is not coming for line in D3 Chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a 4 values what I am drawing in the d3 chart, for first value I am not getting circle but for rest of the values It's displaying the circle perfectly.

Can someone point one what is the problem ? Thanks.

Code sandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-butterfly-2nnbw)

Code snippet -

```
  g.selectAll("circle")
      .data(data)
      .enter()
      .append("circle")
      .attr("cx", function(d) {
        return xScale(d.startTime);
      })
      .attr("cy", function(d) {
        return yScale(d.magnitude);
      })
      .attr("r", function(d) {
        return 5;
      })
      .on("click", function(d) {
        alert("on click" + d.magnitude);
      })
      .attr("class", "circle");
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have a circle in your legend. Therefore, when you do...

```
g.selectAll("circle")
```

... you are selecting that circle and appending a data point to it.

The solution is selecting nothing:

```
g.selectAll(null)
```

Or, if you plan to have an update selection, select by class:

```
g.selectAll(".foo")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("class", "foo)
  //etc...
```

Here is the result: https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-joliot-golgz?fontsize=14

Comment: Thanks, what I see we are just adding a class attr and selecting g.selectAll(".foo") that's all,

Comment: one more thing one same note can I move the chart a bit right side so my circle is fully visible,  because if we notice circle is half visible. please suggest. Thanks

Comment: any suggestions ?

Comment: That's a different problem so please post a new question with the relevant details, it's quite complicated answering questions in the comments section. Also, I'll refrain from checking code on CodeSandbox from now on, it's a complicated and slow site for such a simple thing as a D3 code. Best of luck.

Comment: Sure, Thanks for your help.